# Node MSSQL: trying to insert a row using a function

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I'm writing a function which makes an insert using `mssql` every time it is called. The function received 2 params (action, user), which is the data inserted into the SQL Server table.

Function looks like this:

```
function saveActionToDB(action, user) {
    if (config.Logging.DB.type == 'mssql') {
        const dbOptions = {
            user: config.Logging.DB.user,
            password: config.Logging.DB.password,
            server: config.Logging.DB.server,
            database: config.Logging.DB.database,
            options: {
                encrypt: config.Logging.DB.encrypt
            }
        };
        const database = require('mssql');
        const emmitQuery = async () => {
            try {
                const pool = await database.connect(dbOptions);
                const request = pool.request();
                request.input('action', sql.VarChar, action);
                request.input('user', sql.VarChar, user);
                request.query('insert into actions (action, user) values (@action, @user)', (err, result)=>{
                    //if (err) combinedLogger.error(err);
                });
            }
            catch (err) {
                combinedLogger.error(err);
            }
        }
        emmitQuery();
    }
    else if(config.Logging.DB.type == 'oracle') {
        //oracle
    }
}
```

However, I am getting a console error with "undefined", which means that the try is catching an error, however, the err it's undefined, so I can't figure out what the error is.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You shouldn't be using a callback to `request.query` with `async`/`await`. Try `const result = await request.query`

Comment: @ExplosionPills same thing happens... the catch is being executed with an err = undefined